# 2D harmonic oscillator having 4 constants of the motion and superintegrability

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

A 2D harmonic oscillator
\begin{align}
H=p_x^2+p_y^2+x^2+y^2
\end{align}
has 4 constants of the motion: $E$ the total energy, $D$ the energy difference between coordinates, $L$ the angular momentum and $K$ the correlation. For example see https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1971258

I often read that a system can have at most $2n-1$ constants of the motion, and such a system is maximally superintegrable. In this case $n=2$, implies the most constants of motions the system can have being 3.

Further a 3D harmonic oscillator has 9 constants of the motion, and $9>5$.

How is this reconciled?

Comment: Related [253981](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253981/why-are-there-only-3-additive-integrals-of-motion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The four invariants
$$
2E_x=p_x^2+x^2, \qquad 2E_y=p_y^2+y^2, \qquad L=yp_x-xp_y, \qquad K=xy+p_xp_y,
$$
are linearly independent, as per the requirement of that article's linear algebraic method; but they are not algebraically independent quantities, of course, qua hypersurfaces in the 4d phase space.

You may readily check that 
$$
L^2+K^2=4E_xE_y.
$$
This is a good thing, so that there *is* a trajectory in phase space, and the particle is not frozen: The particle must lie on all constant surfaces, and its trajectory is the intersection of any three. An independent one would intersect it at a point and freeze it!

Recall that the symmetry of the system is SU(2). The 4 invariants represent the 3 generators $L,K,2(E_x-E_y)$ *and* the identity (Hamiltonian), so, then, the quadratic Casimir invariant thereof.

The analogous dependence is at work, more strikingly, in the 3d oscillator, cf [194768](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194768/is-there-an-analog-to-the-runge-lenz-vector-for-a-harmonic-potential), whose [symmetry is SU(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Symmetry_group_of_the_3D_oscillator_Hamiltonian_operator). You might choose the independent set $E_1,E_2,E_3,L_{12},L_{23}$.

But, as a rule, in *n*d, you have 2 *n*–1 independent invariants, so a completely specified trajectory as their intersection——superintegrability.

Comment: I realize this may be technical but do you really mean $su(2)$ and not $u(2)$?

Comment: No, you got me; technical. Yes, the identity, and also Casimir of the *su(2)* , has no problem packing together with it to a *u(2)*, Lie algebraically. Reveals my concern to *shed* invariants, not pile them up...!