# Quantity conserved for the 3D spherically symmetric harmonic potential $V(r)=\alpha r^2$

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

I know that in the case of the Kepler problem there is a quantity (other than energy, momentum,...) conserved which is the Runge-Lenz vector.

Is there also an "exotic" quantity conserved for a 2-Body system with a potential: $V(r)=\alpha r^2$? I'm asking this because the radial harmonic oscillator and the inverse square force are the only ones that have a bounded orbit.

If the answer is positive; is there a symmetry associated to the conservation of this quantity?

Comment: [Close](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194768/is-there-an-analog-to-the-runge-lenz-vector-for-a-harmonic-potential).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an analog to the Runge-Lenz vector for a harmonic potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194768/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3D spherically symmetric harmonic oscillator $$ H~=~\frac{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2}{2m}+ \alpha (x^2+y^2+z^2) ~=~ H_x + H_y + H_z $$ is a separable, [Liouville integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system#Hamiltonian_systems_and_Liouville_integrability), and in fact a maximally [superintegrable system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintegrable_Hamiltonian_system) with additionally integrals of motion $H_x$, $H_y$, $H_z$, $L_x$, $L_y$ and $L_z$, i.e. nothing exotic like the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector. (A 3D system can maximally have 5 independent integrals of motion, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55861/2451) Phys.SE post.)